# Dúvida sobre Registration ID no Google Cloud Message

Tags: android

Estou querendo implementar o GCM no meu projeto, mas estou com algumas dúvidas e precisava tirar todas antes de fazer.

Bom quando eu registro um aparelho no servidor GCM, o id que ele recebe é único? Se eu desinstalar a aplicação e instalar novamente, eu posso garantir que aquele aparelho já é registrado, ou seja, ele usa o id que foi criado uma única vez?

Eu queria que o usuário pudesse se registrar em um aparelho, mas quando ele logasse em outro aparelho tendo o mesmo id do GCM, para que dois aparelhos recebessem a mensagem juntos, mas isso não é possível certo?

Comment: Pelo que li na documentação, o Registration ID é único para o par Dispositivo/Aplicativo (salvo por atualizações que não é recomendado usar o mesmo ID). Se desinstalar e instalar (na mesma versão) o ID é o mesmo. De uma olhada nesses links: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#reg-state e http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Bom quando eu registro um aparelho no servidor GCM, o id que ele recebe é único? Se eu desinstalar a aplicação e instalar novamente, eu posso garantir que aquele aparelho já é registrado, ou seja, ele usa o id que foi criado uma única vez?

**Resposta:**

Sim, é garantido mesmo com a desinstalação, pois o registration ID seria o [IMEI](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Equipment_Identity) do dispositivo.

> Eu queria que o usuário pudesse se registrar em um aparelho, mas quando ele logasse em outro aparelho tendo o mesmo id do GCM, para que dois aparelhos recebessem a mensagem juntos, mas isso não é possível certo?

**Resposta**

Cria uma estrutura de persistência de dados do usuário, onde você armazena no momento do login o registration_id para puder enviar as notificações de push para os usuários.

**Exemplo:**

**Tabela de registration_id**

```
gcm_id | id_usuario |

1          2
2          2
3          1
```

**Tabela de Usuário**

```
id | nome |
2    Caio
3    Julio
```

Dispara as notificações do Caio para os celulares de IMEI 1 e 2